# Google Play console REST API get subscription details

Tags: api, google-play-console, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to use this [API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get) to get subscription information but I get the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
        "domain": "androidpublisher",
        "reason": "projectNotLinked"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have enabled Google Play Android Developer API in the Google Cloud Platform.
and also completed all OAuth consent screen and set up the scope

Ref [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EerPHwks5N0)

Comment: Did you find a solution

Comment: I did not. I will make sure to update this thread if I find the answer.

Comment: I am also getting same issue.

Comment: @NishuthanS wondrrig if you managed to get soloution I am having the same issue

Comment: im having the same issue :(